# Pair AirPods Pro 2 with 2 different Apple devices with 2 different Apple IDs

Tags: macos, iphone, apple-id, bluetooth, airpods

I've had the same problem with my AirPods 1 but somehow managed it some time.
I now got my brand new AirPods 2 (A3048) with Version 6B32 (Case 61.3.0).

I [factory-reset them](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463) and successfully [paired them](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208718) with my iPhone 12 Pro (iOS 17.1.1).
Afterwards I followed the instructions on the help page to connect them to my MacBook Pro (M2 Max 16" 2023, macOS Sonoma 14.1.1) while not pressing the setup button for longer than 5 seconds. Both the iPhone and the MacBook have different Apple ID connections (phone personal / mac work account).

The pairing again was successful, but it seems it reassigned the Apple ID as well (while I first paired with my personal one on my iPhone) to my work's account.
I can successfully switch between devices by selecting the AirPods from the bluetooth menu on the devices, but I get notifications that "an airtag is following me around and the owner might see my location", while this should not be the case as I initially paired them with my personal account which is also connected to my phone.

How is it possible that I assign the AirPods to my personal Apple ID (which is also connected to my iPhone), while being able to pair them as normal bluetooth device to my Mac without re-assigning the ownership?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.